# NSFetchRequestController is not updated Data the first time

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having this issue of **NSFetchRequestController** not updating data the first time when i enter to PhotoVC. lets say, I have **Photographer** and **Photo** entities, one to many relationship respectively "one photographer can have multiple photos",

When i tap on photographer cell, it takes me to photosVC and in the background, i update photos entities however, NSFetchResultController doesnt show me result. HOWEVER, when i hit back and come back to PhotoVC, it shows me data... not sure why **NSFetchResultController** doesn't update the first time??

I use the below mentioned code for FetchResultCOntroller

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultController
{
    if (!_fetchedResultController) {

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Photos.PhotographerID = %@",];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:YES]];
        //[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

        _fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                       managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                         sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        _fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

    }
    return _fetchedResultController;
}
```

Comment: fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Photos.PhotographerID = %@",**photographerID**]; you forgot to add photographer ID after comma(,).

Comment: Have you implemented the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods?

Comment: You mention you are updating the photo entities in the background - is it possible the photo's don't exist the first time?  How do you know the background task has completed ?  If you are doing a background update to the entities you probably need to observe persistentStoreCoordinator notifications and merge the managedObjectContext.